# this reference in Strophe stanza handlers

Tags: javascript, strophe

I have an object for each room I'm joining with Strophe. This object contains a function for handling presence stanzas for this particular room.

```
function Room(name, someData)
    this.name = name;
    this.someData = someData;

    this.presenceHandler = function(presence) {
        console.log(this.name, this.someData);
    }

    this.join = function() {
        connection.addHandler(this.presenceHandler,null,"presence",null,null,this.name);
        connection.send(/*presence*/);
    }
}

var connection = new Strophe.Connection(/*http-bind*/);
var mainRoom = new Room("main", {foo: "bar"});
mainRoom.join();
```

But when the `mainRoom.presenceHandler()` function is called by an stanza by Strophe, `this` in the function refers to the stanza itself and not to `mainRoom` anymore, so I cannot access the attributes from `mainRoom`.

Could you tell me, how I can access the attributes of the room object from within the presenceHandler function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        this.join = function() {
    connection.addHandler(this.presenceHandler,null,"presence",null,null,this.name);
    connection.send(/*presence*/);
}
```

Replace above code with this

```
        var thiss=this;
    this.join = function() {
    connection.addHandler(function(presence)             
    {thiss.presenceHandler(presence);},null,"presence",null,null,this.name);
    connection.send(/*presence*/);
}
```

note the closures for the handler

Answer (score 1):

try initializing the main class again inside the function ...

```
function MainFunc() {

  this.method1 = function() {
    this.property1 = "foo";
  }

  this.method2 = function() {
   var parent = this; // assign the main function to a variable.
   parent.property2 = "bar"; // you can access the main function. using the variable
  }
}
```